# How can I read strings with backslashes?

Tags: clojure

Apparently I can't `read-string` some strings, like

```
user> (read-string "\" \\ABC \"")
RuntimeException Unsupported escape character: \A  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:219)
user>
```

Is there a way around that?

Thanks!

Comment: You've got a good question here. I've been pouring over the docs, and cannot find out how to `(read-string "\\abc")` hoping to add a '\' in front of 'abc'.

Comment: Why do you expect this to work? `read-string` is supposed to read an object from a string that's supposed to represent Clojure code. Strings in Clojure are escaped, just as Java Strings. That's why you need the additional quotation marks around your string (that you've added). It's the same with the backslashes. You need additional ones. `"\ABC"` is not a correct string object in Java/Clojure. What you want is probably `"\\ABC"`, which represents the String `\ABC` in Java & Clojure alike. Am I wrong?

Comment: Got it. Thanks, @Tom. I was trying to read sexps from another lisp, in which "\abc" is a valid string.

Comment: `user> (println (read-string "\"\\\\abc\""))
\abc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to end up with a string that when you print its "\ABC", so:

```
user=> (println "\\ABC")
\ABC
nil
```

As you see, the reader needs two "\". As `read-string` expects the string to be a valid Clojure expression and from your example you are trying to read a string that contains a string, you need to escape both the " (as you are doing) and the **two** \ :

```
user=> (def s (read-string "\" \\\\AB\""))
#'user/s
user=> (class s)
java.lang.String
user=> (println s)
 \AB
nil
user=> s
" \\AB"
```

Comment: Actually I just wanted to read the string (foo "\ABC"), which is valid in a lisp I'm working with, but not in clojure. (.replace slurped "\\" "\\\\") before reading, I guess.